# Deferred deep link - Flutter

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, deferred-deep-linking

I try a lot of ways but I don't know how to set up Deferred deep link for my Flutter App

My idea: User click the link on web and the link will do - if app not install link will navigate to the store to install - if app installed link will navigate to event screen

Please help me resolve this problem or give me some idea to resolve it